# Remove duplicate rows from custom SQL select query

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a table set up that has a unique `Match_ID` for each data entry. However, when I want to call a custom select query that gathers the team name from the `Team` table I get duplicate rows listing two `Match_ID`s that are the same. I want to display rows uniquely in a GridView with columns `Home team`, `Away team`, `Home team score`, `Away team score` and `Game date`. I don't want to display a Team's ID in their columns but instead their Team names. However I also want to make sure I can update this GridView, since using AS has prevented me from being able to do so in the past.

Here's what Im using so far with an image showing what the query returns. I am using an SQL datasource.

```sql
 SELECT        MatchStatistics.Match_ID, MatchStatistics.Home_team_ID, MatchStatistics.Away_team_ID, MatchStatistics.Home_team_score, MatchStatistics.Away_team_score, MatchStatistics.Game_date, 
                         Team.Team_name
FROM            MatchStatistics INNER JOIN
                         Team ON MatchStatistics.Home_team_ID = Team.Team_ID OR MatchStatistics.Away_team_ID = Team.Team_ID
WHERE        EXISTS
                             (SELECT DISTINCT Match_ID
                               FROM            MatchStatistics AS MatchStatistics_1)
```

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="EnterMatchGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Match_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" OnRowUpdating="EnterMatchGridView_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="EnterMatchGridView_RowDeleting">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Match_ID" HeaderText="Match_ID" SortExpression="Match_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Home Team" SortExpression="Home_Team_Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_Team_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_Team_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Away Team" SortExpression="Away_Team_Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Away_Team_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Away_Team_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Home Team Score" SortExpression="Home_team_score">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_team_score") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_team_score") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Away Team Score" SortExpression="Away_team_score">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Away_team_score") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Away_team_score") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Game_date">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Game_date", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Game_date", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit/Delete">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <span onclick="return confirm ('Are you Sure?')">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                    </span>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Update" ConflictDetection="OverwriteChanges" Text="Update" ValidationGroup="EnterMatchGridView" />
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Cancel" ConflictDetection="OverwriteChanges" Text="Cancel" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

[image]

[image]

In short, how do I make this query return unique a unique`MATCH_ID`for each row?

Comment: Just a note: Your `WHERE EXISTS` part is doing nothing. It returns FALSE (0) if the table is empty. Otherwise it allways retuns TRUE (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't that be...

```
SELECT s.Match_ID
     , s.Home_team_ID
     , s.Away_team_ID
     , s.Home_team_score
     , s.Away_team_score
     , s.Game_date
     , h.Team_name home_team
     , a.Team_name away_team
  FROM MatchStatistics s
  JOIN Team h
    ON h.Team_ID = s.Home_team_ID 
  JOIN Team a
    ON a.Team_ID = s.Away_team_ID
```

???

Comment: Ah brilliant thank you! I didn't know you could do that

Comment: Only problem now is updating the GridView. I've made DropDownLists on both home and away team id columns that display their team names, values set to each ID. However regardless, the update query given by the data source says `The parameterized query '(@Match_ID int,@Home_team_ID int,@Away_team_ID int,@Home_team_sc' expects the parameter '@Match_ID', which was not supplied.`

I have parameterised Match_ID so I am not sure why I get this error

Comment: I don't know ASP, so I doubt I can help - but I'm pretty confident that the query ain't the problem.